# Django Date Input Parsing?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to get a date for an event from a user. 
The input is just a simple html text input.
My main problem is that I don't know how to parse the date.

If I try to pass the raw string, I get a TypeError, as expected.

Does Django have any date-parsing modules?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using django.forms look at [DateField.input_formats](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/fields/#datefield). This argument allows to define several date formats. DateField tries to parse raw data according to those formats in order.

Comment: In other words, the OP *should* be using Django forms, which will take care of this if you set input_formats correctly.

Comment: @Roseman: Yes, one possibility. But you can do it without Django forms, I will make an answer.

Answer (score 6):

<del>Django doesn't, so to speak, by Python does.</del> It seems I'm wrong here, as uptimebox's answer shows.

Say you're parsing this string: 'Wed Apr 21 19:29:07 +0000 2010' (This is from Twitter's JSON API)

You'd parse it into a datetime object like this:

```
import datetime

JSON_time = 'Wed Apr 21 19:29:07 +0000 2010'
my_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(JSON_time, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')

print type(my_time)
```

You'd get this, confirming it is a datetime object:

```
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

More information on `strptime()` can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime).

Answer (score 0):

(In 2017), you could now use [django.utils.dateparse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.dateparse)

Answer (score 0):

The DateField can be used outside of Django forms.

Example, when used `{{ value|date:"SHORT_DATE_FORMAT" }}` in template:

```
from django.forms import DateField
from django.utils import formats
# need '%d.%m.%Y' instead of 'd.m.Y' from get_format()
dformat = ('.' + formats.get_format("SHORT_DATE_FORMAT", lang=request.LANGUAGE_CODE)).replace('.', '.%').replace('-', '-%').replace('/', '/%')[1:]
dfield = DateField(input_formats=(dformat,))
<date> = dfield.to_python(<string>)
```